# eclipse jsp - no colors, code completion and error detection

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to find a way to have colors and code completion and error detection in jsp pages. i have

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. 
Version: Helios Service Release 2.

I cannot install anything using the eclipse web tools platform because everything is already installed. any ideas ?

thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are the JSP pages opened with the right editor? Right click on your JSP file -> Open With -> JSP Editor. You can set the editor in Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations.

Comment: thanks a lot! once I opened with 'JSP Editor' it became the default editor and the problem resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Is your project declared as a "Web" or "J2EE" project? If not go into the project facets and add the "Dynamic Web Module" facet to it.

At that point your project /should/ be recognized as a web project and the highlighting and syntax decorations will be enabled.

Comment: under 'Project Facets' I have 'java' and 'Dynamic Web Module' enabled.

Comment: I wonder if the project structure is giving you problems. I would try creating a new project with eclipse and placing your source files within the structure it creates.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this issue by doing this :

Right click on your project then go to Properties -> Targeted Runtime -> Apache tomcat

then restart eclipse.